# Redis connection in multi-threaded environment (Unicorn)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, unicorn

I've been struggling with this error for quite some time:

```
Redis::ProtocolError: Got 'i' as initial reply byte. 
If you're running in a multi-threaded environment, make sure you pass the :thread_safe
option when initializing the connection. If you're in a forking environment, such as 
Unicorn, you need to connect to Redis after forking.
```

It happens intermittently in apps that use Unicorn and Redis. From this [redis-rb Github issue](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/pull/188) it looks the `:thread_safe` option is now enabled by default. I am using `redis 2.2.2` because `redis 3.0.1` is not compatible with the latest version of `resque`.

In my Unicorn config I'm using `Redis.current.quit` after the fork.

I'm also connecting to Redis with a gem called `ruote-redis` which is a storage implementation for the workflow engine Ruote.

How can I ensure that all of my Redis connections are stable and that I don't get this error anymore which is disrupting to the normal use of our app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicorn is not multi-threaded. Are you using threads yourself?

As stated in the docs, the problem you're hitting is that multiple Unicorn workers are sharing the same connection (ie the same underlying file descriptor).

[This change](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/commit/1bd43346cdf71ba69176612714616289a5a70ed4), included in version redis-rb 3.0, makes it even clearer.

If you're still hitting this error please post your Unicorn configuration.

Comment: I'm not using threads. I would love to use redis-rb 3.0 but resque is not compatible with it yet. I've switched the `ruote-redis` gem to `ruote-mon` which uses Mongo for storage. That seems to have resolved the issue.